# React Native why is (only) passing a calculated layout + keyboard hight to style causing infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Unless I use height, no infinite loop is created as I checked, but when I pass the height it does create an infinite loop and only if the list of Items rendered in my 'Autocomplete' component is long. If list is not long its good. What am I doing wrong?Thanks!

```
import { useLayout } from '@react-native-community/hooks'
const App = () => {
    const { onLayout, ...layout } = useLayout()
    const keyboardHeight = useKeyboard(); //custom hook to get keyboard hight
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => { 
      setHeight(layout.height-keyboardHeight);
    },[layout.height, keyboardHeight])
    return (
        <View onLayout={onLayout}>
            <SearchBar />
            <View style={{height: height}}>
                <AutoComplete/> 
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so its either layout.height or keyboardHeight is changing consistently, and most likely its the layout.height because you get the layout height and you change the state height, then the UI will reflct with the new height which will cause the onLayout to calculate the height again and so on. this will create a loop.

onLayout => setHeight (height changed) => onLayout(again) => setHeight ....